# How to force ANTLR to parse all input CharStream

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I'm using ANTLR4 to parse a syntax file. When I use BaseErrorListener to detect errors, I got a problem. When faced with an illegal input string, ANTLR automatically matches the appropriate branch and then **ignores the subsequent stream** of characters even if it contains errors. And I want to detect that error. Here are my g4 file and java file. 
 
  **TransitionLexer** is my lexer file and **TransitionCondition** is my parser file. **ErrorDialogListener.java** is my errorListener and **Test.java** id main java file.

**TransitionLexer.g4**

```
lexer grammar TransitionLexer;

BOOLEAN: 'true' | 'false';
IF: 'if';
THEN: 'then';
ELSE: 'else';

NAME: (ALPHA | CHINESE | '_')(ALPHA | CHINESE | '_'|DIGIT)*;

ALPHA: [a-zA-Z];
CHINESE: [\u4e00-\u9fa5];

NUMBER: INT | REAL;
INT: DIGIT+
    |'(-'DIGIT+')';
REAL: DIGIT+ ('.' DIGIT+)?
    | '(-' DIGIT+ ('.' DIGIT+)? ')';
fragment DIGIT: [0-9];

OPCOMPARE: '='|'>='|'<='|'>'|'<';
WS: [ \t\n\r]+ ->skip;
SL_COMMENT:  '/*' .*? '*/' ->skip;
```

**TransitionCondition.g4**

```
grammar TransitionCondition;
import TransitionLexer;

condition : stat+;
stat : expr;
expr: expr (('and' | 'or') expr)+
    | '(' expr ')'
    | '(' var OPCOMPARE value ')'
    | booleanExpr
    | BOOLEAN
    ;

var: localStates
     | globalStates
     | connector
     ;
localStates: NAME;
globalStates: 'Top' ('.' brick)+ '.' NAME;
connector: brick '.' NAME;

value: userdefinedValue | basicValue;
userdefinedValue: NAME;
basicValue: basicValue op=('*'|'/') basicValue
                    | basicValue op=('+' | '-') basicValue
                    | basicValue ('and' | 'or') basicValue
                    | NUMBER | BOOLEAN
                    | '(' basicValue ')'
                    ;

booleanExpr: booleanExpr OPCOMPARE booleanExpr
           | '(' booleanExpr ')'
           | NUMBER (OPCOMPARE|'*'| '/'|'+'|'-') NUMBER
           ;
brick: NAME;
```

**ErrorDialogListener.java**

```
package errorprocess;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.BaseErrorListener;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.Parser;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.RecognitionException;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.Recognizer;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATNConfigSet;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.dfa.DFA;

public class ErrorDialogListener extends BaseErrorListener {


    @Override
    public void reportContextSensitivity(Parser recognizer, DFA dfa, int startIndex, int stopIndex, int prediction,
            ATNConfigSet configs) {
        System.out.println(dfa.toLexerString());
        System.out.println(dfa.getStates());        
        super.reportContextSensitivity(recognizer, dfa, startIndex, stopIndex, prediction, configs);
    }

    @Override
    public void syntaxError(Recognizer<?, ?> recognizer, Object offendingSymbol, int line, int charPositionInLine,
            String msg, RecognitionException e) {
        List<String> stack = ((Parser)recognizer).getRuleInvocationStack();
        Collections.reverse(stack);
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        buf.append("rule stack: "+stack+" ");
        buf.append("line "+line+":"+charPositionInLine+" at "+
                   offendingSymbol+": "+msg);

        JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        Container contentPane = dialog.getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(new JLabel(buf.toString()));
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.white);
        dialog.setTitle("Syntax error");
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

**Test.java**

```
package errorprocess;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.PredictionMode;

import antlr4.my.transition.TransitionConditionLexer;
import antlr4.my.transition.TransitionConditionParser;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream("G:\\AltaRica\\ANTLR4\\test\\condition\\t.expr");
        ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(in);
        TransitionConditionLexer lexer = new TransitionConditionLexer(input);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        TransitionConditionParser parser = new TransitionConditionParser(tokens);
        parser.removeErrorListeners();
        parser.addErrorListener(new ErrorDialogListener());
//        parser.addErrorListener(new DiagnosticErrorListener());
//        parser.getInterpreter().setPredictionMode(PredictionMode.LL_EXACT_AMBIG_DETECTION);
//        parser.getInterpreter().setPredictionMode(PredictionMode.LL);
        parser.condition();
    }

}
```

## The main problem

When my input is 
**(Top.b2.states = nominal) and (b1.i1 = wrong) and (states >= 5.5)**, the parser works fine. 
 
But when my input is **(Top.b2.states = nominal) aaa (b1.i1 = wrong) and (states >= 5.5)**, the parser only parse **(Top.b2.states = nominal)** and ignores words after **aaa** which is not right with syntax file. 
 
I guess the reason is that the parser follows the second branch of my first rule in TransitionCondition.g4, which is **expr: '(' expr ')'**, and simply ignores others. So How to force ANTLR recognize all input or how to force ANTLR only choose the first branch(**expr:  expr (('and' | 'or') expr)+**) in this situation?

## What I've tried.

I tried to use DiagnosticErrorListener or override reportContextSensitivity() but it seems not worked.

Comment: Have you considered to put EOF in your grammar? Like `effect: expr EOF`. You can find this in several ANTLR4 example gramars.

Comment: Thank you! It seems work!  And sorry for putting the wrong file, there should be **TranstionCondition.g4**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main rule needs to end with the `EOF` token - an ANTLR-provided special token that matches end of input.

If the token's not there, ANTLR will just parse whatever it can match and then stop. By putting the `EOF` at the end of your entry rule, you tell ANTLR that whatever it parses must end at the end of input.

Comment: As far as I know anltr doesn't have a concept of a main rule; the EOF approach will only prevent partial inputs being matched if *none* of the parser grammar rules can accept a prefix of the input string (including the empty string), I believe. This is quite often not true for grammar rules that define sub-parts of the overall program/input (especially those using * at the top level of their rules).

Comment: In ANTLRv3 at least, you as a user (of the generated parser) define the start rule by invoking the associated method. I believe v4 is similar but didn't check.

Answer (score 0):

May be its a late response. Another approach without using `EOF`, you can use `ParserRuleContext#stop` field to determine if complete `input` is parsed or not:

```
// Assuming we are trying to parse input
ParserRuleContext context = parser.condition();
int stopIndex = context.stop.getStopIndex();
assert input.length() - 1 == stopIndex : "Complete input not parsed, remaining part: " + input.substring(stopIndex + 1);
```